# add_principal: DN is out of the realm subtree while creating "principal@REALM.COM"

Tags: ldap, kerberos, sles

I'm trying to create a principal linked to an ldap object according to the MIT documentation.
This is my ldap structure:[LDAP STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjuDA.jpg)

Once I've created the UID object in the Ldap ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com, (cn=nano,dc=people,dc=domain,dc=com), when I try to add the principal with the link dn attached I receive:

```
kadmin.local:  add_principal -x linkdn=uid=nano,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com nano

NOTICE: no policy specified for nano@DOMAIN.COM; assigning "default"
Enter password for principal "nano@DOMAIN.COM":
Re-enter password for principal "nano@DOMAIN.COM":

add_principal: DN is out of the realm subtree while creating "nano@DOMAIN.COM".
```

I've been looking up a solution in the internet and all I've found is a bug [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/krb5/+bug/1817955).

Yast User and Group manager is able to create the user and to create a principal linked to it through the UserKerberosPlugin.

Anybody knows what could I've misconfigurated?

EDIT:
I noticed that it does not recognizing any subtree:

```
dc01:~ # kdb5_ldap_util -r DOMAIN.COM -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -W view
Password for "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com":
               Realm Name: DOMAIN.COM
```

So, I tryed to submit it to the kerberos database:

```
dc01:~ # kdb5_ldap_util -r DOMAIN.COM -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" create -subtrees "ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com" -sscope 2
Password for "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com":
Initializing database for realm 'DOMAIN.COM'
You will be prompted for the database Master Password.
It is important that you NOT FORGET this password.
Enter KDC database master key:
Re-enter KDC database master key to verify:
kdb5_ldap_util: Already exists while creating realm 'DOMAIN.COM'
```

Why could be happening this?

Thank you so much.
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this destroying the database and creating again.

```
kdb5_ldap_util destroy -r DOMAIN.COM
kdb5_ldap_util -r DOMAIN.COM -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=Manager,dc=DOMAIN,dc=com" create -subtrees "ou=people,dc=DOMAIN,dc=com" -sscope 2
kdb5_ldap_util -r DOMAIN.COM -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -W view
```